# How to write url rewriting for [mywebsitename].com/pages/224?task=5 in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written code required for url rewriting of

```
[mywebsitename].com?type=pages&id=22
```

as

```
[mywebsitename].com/pages/224.
```

Now my question is, can i use

```
[mywebsitename].com/pages/224?task=5
```

so that i can use

```
Request.Querystring["task"]
```

in my code?

Comment: Can you upload the code which translates `.com?type=pages&id=22 ` to  `/pages/224. ` ?

Comment: <rewrite url="~/xxxxxxxx/(.+)/(.+?)/" to="~/pagename.aspx?type=$1&amp;Id=$2"/>

Answer (score 0):

I am not up to date on IIS but last time I used it I had to install URL rewrite module in IIS (not sure if ships fro the getgo in newer version) but here is quick tutorial
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module
With URL Rewrite you can still read the query string the traditional way.